# Any notions of operations in basic postulates of lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am learning Lambda Calculus from the book by Hindley and Seldin . They start the formal postulation of lambda calculus as follow :

(a) all variables and atomic constants are λ-terms (called atoms);

(b) if M and N are any λ-terms, then (MN) is a λ-term (called an application);

(c) if M is any λ-term and x is any variable, then (λx.M) is aλ-term (called an abstraction).

In the second postulate $MN$ has been termed as a $\lambda$ term . How to define $MN$ , what does it mean ? Is it an operation?
Is there any scope of defining operations in lambda calculus which are associative and/or distributive  ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last sentence.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of application $MN$ as an algebraic operation, where the operator has been elided for convenience. Instead of $MN$ some people write $M @ N$, or even
$$
apply(M, N)
$$
So $apply(\cdot, \cdot)$  is a binary operation, and, as @chi points out,
 $apply(\cdot, \cdot)$ is is *neither* associative nor commutative. The precise nature of what $apply(\cdot, \cdot)$  does depends on exactly what $\lambda$-calculus you have in mind.

Answer (score 3):

The application $MN$ is just syntax. On its own it does not mean anything.

There is, however, an intuition behind its semantics: $M$ is to be regarded as a function, and $N$ as its argument. Evaluating an application $MN$ simply corresponds to evaluating function $M$ at point $N$. This is formally defined through the $\beta$ reduction law.

Note that application is not associative or commutative. $MN$ is in general different from $NM$, and $MNO$ is an alternative notation for $(MN)O$, which is different from $M(NO)$.

This is not terribly different from any other programming language. Think about `f(x)` and `x(f)`, or `f(x)(y)` and `f(x(y))` in JavaScript, for instance.

Comment: Evaluating the value of a function at a given point , we do it in an abstraction right ? So , in essence , as per your answers , application and abstraction perform the same thing ?

Comment: @AgniveshSingh No, abstraction constructs a function, application uses it. E.g. $\lambda x. x x$ is an abstraction, if you apply it to $M$ you get $(\lambda x. x x) M$ which according to the beta rule reduces to $MM$.